# How can I prevent Elasticsearch from using so much memory?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am attempting to use Kibana to visualize some Bro records that I've ingested into Elasticsearch. I've loaded ~1 month of records (around 3 billion records all together, and ~4TB). The data gets ingested and indexed without issue. I can build some simple visualizations in Kibana, but when I try to load a dashboard that I created (which includes 12 different visualizations, and kicks off at least that many Elasticsearch queries), I start getting errors.

I'm running a 7-node Elasticsearch cluster with 5 data nodes:

```
host001 192.168.1.1 18  8  0.00 - * Feron  
host002 192.168.1.2 15  8  0.00 - - Dark Phoenix    
host003 192.168.1.3 58 21  0.25 d - Starbolt          
host004 192.168.1.4 37 23  0.07 d - Niles Van Roekel  
host005 192.168.1.5 47 29  0.10 d - Angel Salvadore    
host006 192.168.1.6 68 29 16.37 d - Candra            
host007 192.168.1.7 56 29 14.36 d - Algrim the Strong
```

The highlights of the elasticsearch.log errors are as follows:

A collection of these lines for the different Fields (the breakers are hit when using too much memory for field data, which I think is the core of my issue):

> [2015-10-06 08:24:00,265][WARN ][indices.breaker          ] [Eric Slaughter] [FIELDDATA] New used memory 3752926600 [3.4gb] from field [AA] would be larger than configured breaker: 3745107148 [3.4gb], breaking

A collection of these (it seems even with the breakers, Elasticsearch runs out of memory anyway):

> [2015-10-06 08:32:06,279][WARN ][netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector] Unexpected exception in the selector loop.
>   org.elasticsearch.index.engine.CreateFailedEngineException: [bro-2015-10-06][2] Create failed for [dns#AVA9HeN5uS-hcepf0HbN]
>           at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.create(InternalEngine.java:262)
>           at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.create(IndexShard.java:470)
>           at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:437)
>           at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:149)
>           at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:515)
>           at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:422)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: refusing to delete any files: this IndexWriter hit an unrecoverable exception
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.ensureOpen(IndexFileDeleter.java:354)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.deleteFile(IndexFileDeleter.java:719)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.deleteNewFiles(IndexFileDeleter.java:712)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.deleteNewFiles(IndexWriter.java:4821)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$DeleteNewFilesEvent.process(DocumentsWriter.java:749)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.processEvents(IndexWriter.java:4875)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.processEvents(IndexWriter.java:4867)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1527)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1252)
>           at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.innerCreateNoLock(InternalEngine.java:343)
>           at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.innerCreate(InternalEngine.java:285)
>           at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.create(InternalEngine.java:256)
>           ... 8 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

And then a bunch of the following, which I believe is an attempt to bring up a replica shard on another node (which will then cause THAT node to fail, and begin a chain reaction... I've gotten rid of this error by eliminating replica shards, but I'd prefer a better solution)

> [2015-10-06 08:38:35,707][WARN ][action.bulk              ] [Eric Slaughter] Failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on remote replica [Tower][KxzEXAXKTCazjLzgOJE_aA][host005][inet[/192.168.1.5:9300]]{master=false}[bro-2015-10-06][8]
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [Tower][inet[/192.168.1.5:9300]][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]] disconnected

I understand that one way to solve this problem is to scale horizontally, but I do not have such a luxury, and I would prefer to be able to properly utilize the cluster that I have (especially since I'm only using 0.5TB of data and there is a lot more available).

I also have researched a few other options that can be seen in my mapping below. The "doc_values" format of data is supposed to load the field data on disk, but it does not completely eliminate the issue. It's possible that there is something else eating up all of the memory, or that the meta-fields (_type, _id, etc.) are to blame (since I have not found a way to configure those with "doc_values").  I also am using global ordinals for string fields.

If anyone needs more info about my cluster or config, let me know!  I'm really stumped on this, so thanks in advance for any help that you guys can offer.

Here is the mapping template that I used: http://pastebin.com/S8UVKRxZ

Here are my elasticsearch.yml configs: http://pastebin.com/PaG0pBC5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many records do you have per index? If the amount of records per index are in the billions you may want to break your indexes out.

^^ I would prefer this to be a comment, but due to my low reputation I cannot comment on your question.

From ElasticSearch's documentation:
[limiting_memory_usage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html)

> It may surprise you to find that Elasticsearch does not load into
>   fielddata just the values for the documents that match your query. It
>   loads the values for all documents in your index, even documents with
>   a different _type!

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Currently, all of the records is stored in one index.  I can certainly try breaking them up into smaller ones, but out of curiosity why would this help?  I would think that more indices would result in more memory usage.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Perhaps the queries will not require ALL the data from one large index, but just the data of some indices, that are smaller than the sum of all the data you store.

Comment: This did solve my memory issues, and I no longer experience out of memory errors when loading dashboards!  Thanks.